# how to wait for an iframe to load in selenium python with phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Script for page to get is

```
 from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        import unittest     
        import time, re, castro
        class  LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

            def setUp(self):
                self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
                self.driver.maximize_window()
                self.driver.get("xxx.html") # getting the page
                "wanna wait her"
                print self.driver.save_screenshot("fire.png")

            def tearDown(self):     
                self.driver.quit()

        if __name__ == '__main__' :
            unittest.main()
```

HTML Code for `iframe`:

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://thunder/spidio.net/CF9F4DA6B7533431/devinfo/devdect   /d,,,_STN&pg=Post=&ckid=null&ord=123&p=mts&cid=0&pid=124" style="background-color: transparent; border : 0px none transparent; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;" height="1" width"1">
    </iframe>
</body>
```

please let me know how to make selenium wait for this iframe to be loaded in phantomjs with selenium using python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below code to wait until required `iframe` appears:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'http://thunder/spidio.net/CF9F4DA6B7533431/devinfo/devdect')]")))
```

Comment: I'm using the above code to wait for the iframe but it terminates the connection as soon as the page load , the iframe basically loads a video , how can i wait until the video completes, i have two options 
1) that to wait until an alert is given after the completion of iframe
2) that to wait until the video completes
what should i prefer and how to accomplish it

Comment: Is there any new elements present after video playback completion? Something like "Play again", "Next video" or something like that? Can you share page `URL` or it is confidential info?

Comment: can i DM you somewhere

Comment: What does it mean `DM`? sorry, I don't know this abbreviation

Comment: direct message rather than posting here