# Python Selenium: How to wait and switch to a dynamic iframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am currently scraping [this website](https://www.bungol.ca).

The site has google maps iframe embedded in it. It refreshes every time I enter an address in the search box. 
*How do I check until the map finish refreshing?*

I am currently using:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")))
```

I'm unsure if this works because my internet is too fast for me to test it out.

I have checked the [definitions of waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in the selenium website but I do not understand what they mean.

I also found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276027/how-to-wait-for-an-iframe-to-load-in-selenium-python-with-phantomjs) which uses the same method but unsure if it waits for the iframe to load initially only or it waits for it to change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this code:

```
driver.get('https://www.bungol.ca/map/location/scarborough/?')
time.sleep(3)

refresh_count = 0
while True:
    try:
        driver.refresh()
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")))
        el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")
        assert el.is_displayed()
        refresh_count += 1
    except Exception:
        print("Refresh count = " + str(refresh_count))
```

And the output was:

```
Refresh count = 0
Refresh count = 43
Refresh count = 44
Refresh count = 56
Refresh count = 62
Refresh count = 63
Refresh count = 64
Refresh count = 68
Refresh count = 69
```

The `iframe` was not in the `DOM` at 0, 43, 44, ... . The first time it failed because of the long first load. Then it was good and I decided to simulate slow connection by toggling `Chrome` to mobile version. And then it failed already relative often.

And then I have set `WebDriverWait`:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.refresh()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")))
        el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")
        assert el.is_displayed()
        refresh_count += 1
    except Exception:
        print("Refresh count = " + str(refresh_count))
```

and it didn't throw any exception. So you can use `EC.presence_of_element_...`

Answer (score 2):

As per your question if you intend to switch to the `<iframe>` identified as `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `<iframe>` *to be available and switch to it* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".gm-style > iframe:nth-child(2)")))
```